# How to create categories menù in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, blogs

I am new in WordPress world (before now I always used Joomla and some other old CMS)

Now I am testing WordPress and I have some doubts about how create a navigation menù in my WP Site.

This is my test site (that at this time have not content but only a template): http://www.scorejava.com/WPTest/

I plan to create articles organized by category and I would have an horizontal top menù like this WP blog: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/

As you can see in this second WP site there is an horizzontal top menù that contains some voices, like **"Java"**, clicking on this voice appear a page showing all the Java posts preview.

As you can see this menù work also with submenù, for example, moving the mouse curso on Java appear the "Java EE" subvoice.

What can I do to have something like this in my Word Press?

And if I want a similar vertical menù in my right sidebar?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to WPSE

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of using the "menus" screen from the Dashboard (when you're there, click on "Screen options" and enable all the possible item sources you want to use). Once you've created your menu, assign it to whatever area your theme designates for the top menu.

If you want to add it to a sidebar, just use the "widgets" screen and pick the "custom menus" item.

I think it would help if you read some of the introductory documentation from the Codex.